# C# WPF dispatcher - can't get it right

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I am trying to make a change in the UI and then make my function run
here's my code:

```
private void btnAddChange_Document(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   System.Threading.ThreadStart start = delegate()
   {
      // ...

      // This will throw an exception 
      // (it's on the wrong thread)
      Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(changest));

      //this.BusyIndicator_CompSelect.IsBusy = true;
      
      //this.MainWindow_parent.BusyIndicator_MainWindow.IsBusy = true;
   };
   // Create the thread and kick it started!
   new System.Threading.Thread(start).Start();
}

public void changest()
{
    this.BusyIndicator_CompSelect.IsBusy = true;
    this.MainWindow_parent.BusyIndicator_MainWindow.IsBusy = true;
    t = "Creating document 1/2..";
}
```

the function I want to run after the ui updates / after the ThreadStart 'start' has ended:

```
string x = "";
for(int i =0;i<=1000;i++)
{
   x+= i.ToString();
}
MessageBox.Show(x);
```

So what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to execute some action asynchronous. Right? For this, I recommend using in WPF the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)-class:

```
BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker() { WorkerReportsProgress=true};  
bgWorker.DoWork += (s, e) => {      
    // Do here your work
    // Use bgWorker.ReportProgress(); to report the current progress  
};  
bgWorker.ProgressChanged+=(s,e)=>{      
    // Here you will be informed about progress and here it is save to change/show progress. 
    // You can access from here savely a ProgressBars or another control.  
};  
bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => {      
   // Here you will be informed if the job is done. 
   // Use this event to unlock your gui 
};  
// Lock here your GUI
bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

I hope, this is what your question is about.

Comment: Here's what i tried (doesn't seem to work =/): bgWorker.DoWork += (s, ev) => {
bgWorker.ReportProgress(); to report the current progress  
this.BusyIndicator_CompSelect.IsBusy = true;
this.MainWindow_parent.BusyIndicator_MainWindow.IsBusy = true;
t = "Creating document 1/2..";
bgWorker.ReportProgress(100);
};
bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, ev) =>
{
this.MainWindow_parent.MyAddDocumentFunc(lbOS.SelectedValue.ToString(), lbVersion.SelectedValue.ToString());
};
bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

Comment: @dinbrca: What happens? Which exception/error behaviour do you have?

Comment: no exception occured, though it seems like the IsBusy values don't change =/

Comment: @dinbrca: I have not seen any worker code. May it be that it is so fast executed that you dont see a change? For testing, you can add Thread.Sleep(1000) into the DoWork-event. This will pause the worker thread for a second. In the RunWorkerCompleted-event you have to set the IsBusy-property back to false.

Comment: at last! success!, i have needed to add a dispatcher to your code :) thanks for the ongoing fast responses =]

Comment: you wont be able to make ui changes from a background thread you will need to use the dispatcher

Answer (score 1):

Slightly confused on what you are trying to accomplish but I believe this is what you are after...

```
    private void btnAddChange_Document(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.ThreadStart start = delegate()
        {
            //do intensive work; on background thread
            string x = "";
            for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
            {
                x += i.ToString();
            }

            //done doing work, send result to the UI thread
            Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                new Action<int>(changest));

        };

        //perform UI work before we start the new thread
        this.BusyIndicator_CompSelect.IsBusy = true;
        this.MainWindow_parent.BusyIndicator_MainWindow.IsBusy = true;
        t = "Creating document 1/2..";

        //create new thread, start it
        new System.Threading.Thread(start).Start();
    }

    public void changest(int x)
    {
        //show the result on the UI thread
        MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: it seems like it firsts creates a new document and then it changes the IsBusy value to true. because the BusyIndicator shows up after the document had been created. i use the BusyIndicator of the "Extended WPF Toolkit".